# How to create docker image of existing WAS 8.5.5.14?

Tags: docker, websphere

I have Websphere Application Server 8.5.5.14 hosting my ERP. I want to dockerize the application and deploy it into Kubernetes cluster. Can anyone provide me information on how to create image out of my existing WAS 8.5.5.14.

Answer (score 2):

In theory you could do this by creating a tar ball of the filesystem and importing it into docker to make an image via something like:
`cat WAS.tar | docker import - appImage`
but there's going to be a number of issues you'll need to avoid, for example, if you have resources (jdbc drivers,resource adapters, etc), the tarball will need to have all of those included.  You'll also need to expose all of the required ports for your app and its administration.  A better way and best practice to solve this would be to start with an IBM supported image of traditional WAS and build your system atop it.
There are detailed instructions to do this at https://github.com/WASdev/ci.docker.websphere-traditional#docker-hub-image

Answer (score 0):

F Rowe's answer is good; if you follow their advice of using the official images you will be using WebSphere v9.0 in the container. You can use [this tool](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/#asset/tools-Migration_Toolkit_for_Application_Binaries) that can help figure out if there are any changes you need to make to your application in order to get it working in the container. It also generates some of the wsadmin scripts to configure the server in the image.